# ¿Como hacer un método abstracto para cerrar el teclado virtual?

Tags: java, android-studio

mi pregunta es ¿Cómo podría modificar el siente método para hacerlo abstracto y poder llamarlo en la clase que lo necesite?

```
private void cerrarTeclado(){
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Lo que hace el método es cerrar el teclado virtual. el problema es que no se como adaptarlo para poder convertirlo en abstracto y llamarlo desde la clase que lo necesito. Ya que así como esta da error por getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE).

la idea es por ejemplo tener una clase que se llame MetodosUtiles en donde este abstract cerrarTeclado(). y poder llamarlo con MetodosUtiles.cerrarTeclado() cada vez que lo necesite, y no tener que repetir código en todas las clases que necesite este método.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder llamarlo desde otra clase debes enviar el contexto en este caso el de la Activity para poder llamar los métodos `getCurrentFocus()` y `getSystemService()` , realiza el siguiente cambio en tu método:

```
private void cerrarTeclado(@NonNull Activity activity){
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

y llama el método agregando como parámetro la activity